# Big-O when iterations do not correlate with input

Tags: time-complexity

Sorry for the perhaps basic question, but my time at university is *long* ago and I need to brush up on Big-O stuff for interviews.

My question is, what would the time complexity be when an algorithm *does* depend on the input but not on the size of the input? For example, assume I have this function:

```
func doSomething(numbers []int) int {
    // find maximum number
    maxNumber := max(numbers)
    for i := 0; i < maxNumber; i++ {
      // magic happens here
    }
}

func maxNumber(numbers []int) (max int) {
     for _,num := range numbers {
           if num > max {
              max = num
            }
     }
     return max
}
```

How would you define the Time-Complexity of `doSomething`? The amount of iterations happens to be the maximum number in the input, so if the input is `[1000000]` we  get `1000000` iterations with input size `1`. Yet if the input would be `[1,1,1,1,1,....]` the iteration would still only be `1` even though our input size would be much greater.

Of course the `maxNumber` would be `O(n)` but my understanding is that you would ignore  this in the calculation of `doSomething`.

I could say `O(1)` because it's not dependent of the input size, but that seems wrong to me because different input *could* have different iterations.

Answer (score 1):

The time complexity of `doSomething` is $O(\max(n,m))$, where $n$ is the length of the input, and $m$ is the maximum number in the input. The letter $m$ is not standard – you can use a different one if you prefer.